# Retrieving Bootstrap Dropdown Selection Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to find out how to do this anywhere except inside the onClick event from the dropdowns itself which won't work since I need to get both of them at the same time.

I am trying to retrieve the selected text values from the dropdowns when a user pushes the SUBMIT button.

Here is the HTML and Javascript Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
        <span class="select" id="datacenter_select">
                    <button type="button" id="datacenter_select_btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="selected">Data Center</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu option" role="menu">
                        <li id="1"><a href="#">option1</a></li>
                        <li id="2"><a href="#">option2</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </span>
        <span class="select" id="state_select">
                    <button type="button" id="state_select_btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="selected">State</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
                    <ul id="state_select_ul" class="dropdown-menu option" role="menu">
                    <li id="1"><a href="#">state1</a></li>
                    <li id="2"><a href="#">state2</a></li>
                    <li id="3"><a href="#">state3</a></li>
                    </ul>
        </span>
        <button type="button" id="state_submit_btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle submit_buttons">Submit</button>
</div> <!--columns -->
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready() {
function gen_state(STATE_SELECTION,DATACENTER_SELECTION) {
    $.ajax(
        {
        url: "get_state.php?state=STATE_SELECTION&datacenter=DATACENTER_SELECTION",
        async: false,
        success: function(data)
            {
            document.getElementById("state_results").innerHTML = data;
            }
        }
        )
    return;
    }

$('#datacenter_select').on('click','.option li',function(){
    var i = $(this).parents('.select').attr('id');
    var DATACENTER_SELECTION = $(this).children().text();
    var o = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+i+' .selected').attr('id',o);
    $('#'+i+' .selected').text(DATACENTER_SELECTION);
    });

$('#state_select').on('click','.option li',function(){
    var i = $(this).parents('.select').attr('id');
    var STATE_SELECTION = $(this).children().text();
    var o = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+i+' .selected').attr('id',o);
    $('#'+i+' .selected').text(STATE_SELECTION);
    });

$('#state_submit_btn').on('click', function () {
    var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
    gen_state(STATE_SELECTION,DATACENTER_SELECTION);
    $btn.button('reset');
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bit too much for a simple task ...

Your way but cleaner: [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ln3tnxe0/)

**JS**:

```
$(function(){
    $('.select').on('click','.option li a',function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var i = $(this).closest('.select').find('span.selected').text($(this).text());
    });
    $('#state_submit_btn').on('click', function () {
        var $btn = $(this).button('loading');
        gen_state();
        $btn.button('reset');
    });

});
function gen_state() {
    var state_select = $("#state_select").find('span.selected').text();
    var center_select = $("#datacenter_select").find('span.selected').text();
    alert(state_select + " " + center_select);
    //Procceed with ajax:
}
```

And another thing you should know:

For domReady execution block the syntax is:

`$(document).ready(function(){ /* YOUR CODE */});`

Not

`$(document).ready() {}`

And you can also use: `$(function(){ /* YOUR CODE */ });`

Have fun.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. I need to learn more about the parent/child stuff in the DOM.

Comment: Great - if it answered your question - don't forget to accept it.